# Copy a file to clipboard

Tags: java, linux, file, clipboard

I'm trying to copy a file into the system's clipboard. As i found in the internet I'm trying to achieve this like this:

```
final List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
files.add(new File("pathToFile"));

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
    new Transferable() {
    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavor);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        return files;
    }
}, null);
```

However after I run that code I'm not able fo paste the file from clipboard (tried on the desktop and in the system explorer). I have even tried to put in a sleep afterwards because I have read that the JVM must be running in order to be ablke to paste that clipboard content but it didn't work for me.
Nevertheless `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);` is returning the respective file I copied into clipboard.
One thing that I did find out was that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);` returns `false`. Does that mean that the clipboard does not support files? That wouldn't make sense as I am able to copy paste files in the explorer using Ctlr+C and Ctrl+V.

I don't know if it's important but I'm running my tests under Linux Mint.

Can anyone explain to me why I can't paste that copied file or how I have to copy it in order to be able to paste it via Ctrl+V system wide?

Comment: This question comes up from time to time but is never answered.

Comment: I experimented with it a bit. When I copy files from the Finder (I'm on a Mac) ,the clipboard as seen by Java is populated with the "Java file list" flavor as well as a bunch of other flavors that seem to be representations of the file list as String, Reader, char array, etc. Yet populating the clipboard myself with the "Java file list" doesn't inspire Finder to let me paste those files into a folder.

Comment: What's really weird is that if I set a "Java file list" into the clipboard and then immediately retrieve it, I get a "Java file list," just as I'd expect. But if I then run my Java program again and inspect the clipboard, it has a lot of new representations similar to the ones that I see when copying from the Finder. So something seems to be augmenting the clipboard after my Java program places the content there. Maybe this is a Mac thing.

Comment: I think that your best strategy is to copy files from your desktop, see how they look in the clipboard both from Java and from Linux (there's probably a clipboard viewer program somewhere), and then try to replicate that state from Java.

Comment: It seems like when copying via Ctrl+C the clipboard contains a `ClipboardTransferable` object but if I try to create one myself the compiler tells me that there is no such class... When using the normal `Transferable` as a clipboard content it is stored as a `TransferableProxy`

Comment: The next thing that caught my attention is that whatever I copy into the clipboard programmatically is not persistent. If I start the application again and access the clipboard content before setting it it is always the `ClipboardTransferable` that corresponds to the thing that I have copied via Ctrl+C

Comment: Okay that may be why I observed that the Mac was changing the clipboard after I pasted something into it. I could have just been restoring the prior state.